# selecting whole entities from SQLAlchemy subqueries

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

If I specify mapped classes (~= database tables) in a SQLAlchemy query, then the returned rows will contain instances of those classes:

```
q = sess.query(table1, table2, table3.string_column)
q.first()
==> ( <instance of table1>,
      <instance of table2>,
      'string' )
```

However, if I select from a subquery, then the returned rows contain the individual columns rather than the class instances:

```
q = sess.query(table1, table2, table3.string_column)

q2 = sess.query( q.subquery() )
q2.first()
==> ( col1_of_table1, col2_of_table1, ...,
      col2_of_table2, col2_of_table2, ...,
      'string' )
```

Is there a way to specify that I want to preserve the row from the subquery as an instance of a mapped class?

I can't figure out how to do this without joining to a new instance of the mapped classes. The [`corresponding_column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Alias.corresponding_column) method allows me to refer to specific **columns** from the subquery, but I can't figure out how to refer to complete entities from the subquery. I've tried playing around with [`select_from`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.select_from) but it doesn't give me the right behavior.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the query that returns entities always needs to be told about those entities - thats the things it wants to "select".  The source of rows is what it wants to select "from".   Two separate things.

so given:

```
q = sess.query(table1, table2, table3.string_column)
q = q.subquery()
```

once you call subquery(), the ORM-ness of the query is mostly gone, it's just a SELECT object.  To select entities from that you have to name them out again, and use select_entity_from (which if you are actually on 0.7, is what select_from() was back then; you'd need to be specific about "not the right behavior):

```
q2 = sess.query(table1, table2, table3.string_column).select_entity_from(q)
```

Comment: Loved the term "the ORM-ness"

Answer (score 1):

According to [Selecting Entities from Subqueries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries), you can use keyword aliased()

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: This is a better solution!